# Splitting file document and sorting it

Tags: python

I have made a dice game which has a valid login system, which verifies if a user's account is present and allow him to create a new one. It then proceeds to the game itself, where it adds 10 points to the dice total if the number is even and subtracts 5 if the number is odd. I have it all fully working, but the only thing that I cant seem to get right is splitting the file document where the username and score is stored and sorting it by score.

```
winner = (Winner_points,',',winner_user)
f = open('Winner.txt','a')
f.write(str(winner))
f.write('\n')
f.close()
```

How can I split the string into 2, and then sort it by the winner points, which then can be stored on a separate document?

Comment: what do you mean by splitting it to two? do you what to separate documents? or the `string` inside it, how is it store the string in the file right now?

Comment: I have it in the format (number , username) without the brackets.

Comment: and I want to sort it in the ascending order by the number on a separate document

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look into python's [split](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) method. This will return an array of the two sides of the string from the delimiter.

```py
splitted_array = winner.split(',')
```

Index 0 would be the winner's points, and Index 1 is the winner user.

In terms of sorting it, consider using appending all winners into a list called `winners` like this:

```py
[[200, "winner1"], [100, "winner2"], [300, "winner3"]]
```

Then you can use the `sorted` method to sort the list, using `operator` to locate the index:

```py
import operator
sorted(winners, key=operator.itemgetter(0))
```

Output:

```
[[100, 'winner1'], [200, 'winner2'], [300, 'winner3']]
```

If you want to sort by descending order, simply add `reverse=True` to the parameters.

Comment: Thanks, how would I then sort it in ascending order on a separate document?

Comment: @TheGr4nd I just added that information to the answer :)

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot!

Comment: Hey, do you know what I would need to do to sort it inside the text document 'winner.txt'?

Comment: You might want to use the `w` (Write) mode when opening the file. That will replace the existing contents

Comment: I think I know how to do it. It involves adding the points and user in the format you suggested and sorting them using the operator, but I dont know how I can make it so that the list doesnt delete itself after the game is restarted. What I have right now is:winners = []
winners.append([Winner_points, winner_user])
sorted(winners, key=operator.itemgetter(0))

Comment: You might want to save the entire game into another file. Instead of using `w`, use `a`(append) the data into the new file. Then every time you would sort the new file so it's ordered by score. That will prevent the problem you're describing

Comment: Hi @TheGr4nd, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.